Solve $x^3+x^2+x=-\frac{1}{3}$ in $\mathbb{R}$
Good evening.
I was able to solve the equation $x^3+x^2+x=-\frac{1}{3}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with Cardano's formula.
I was wondering if there was another method or trick to solve it, maybe in a more beautiful way?
Thank you for your time.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS threads third degree and Equation olymp perfect one ., both of which use alternate approaches which are "relatively" simple and, thus, which you might consider to be "... a more beautiful way". There's also the related How many roots are rational? asking for just # of rational roots (as title implies).

You may write the equation $$3x^3+3x^2+3x+1=2x^3+(x+1)^3=0$$ So $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3=-2$$

More beautiful way ? No. But still a "standard" way to solve cubics in $\mathbb{C}
$ by converting it to a depressed cubic.
(This seems like a competition type problem so the way you solved it or the way @cansomeonehelpmeout mentioned are probably the intended ways to go about it since usualy competition problems have unique and "fast" solutions)
after adding $1\over3$ to both sides and factoring it out we get :
$$3x^3+3x^2+3x+1=0\iff1+3(x-\frac{1}{3})+3(x-\frac{1}{3})^2+3(x-\frac{1}{3})^3=0$$
Under $x=t+\frac{1}{3}$ the equation becomes
$$3t^3+2t+\frac{2}{9}=0\iff t^3+\frac{2t}{3}+\frac{2}{27}=0$$
WLOG we can write $t$ as $y+\frac{λ}{y}$ where $λ$ is a constant.
$$y^6+y^4(3λ+\frac{2}{3})+\frac{2y^2}{27}+y^2(3λ^2+\frac{2λ}{3})+λ^2=0$$
Substituting $λ=-\frac{2}{9}$ and $z=y^3$ gives birth to a quadratic equation in the variable $z$
$$z^2+\frac{2z}{27}-\frac{8}{729}=0\iff z=\frac{2}{27}\iff y=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}\lor y=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-2}}{3}\lor y=\frac{1}{3}(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{2}$$ That gives the results:
$$x=\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt[3]{2}-2^{2/3}
)\lor x=-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-2}(\sqrt[3]{-2}
+1)-\frac{1}{3} \lor x=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-2}(\sqrt[3]{-1}+\sqrt[3]{2})-\frac{1}{3}$$
EDIT
This may not be considered an actual answer to the question but , I still think it holds some value.
